# how to make python to wait until batch execution get complete

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess

Path = location of batch file.(c:....\a.bat)

And a.bat contain following data:
START C:\Python27\python.exe "C:.....\test.py"

I have the following code:

```
      my_process = subprocess.call(os.path.abspath(path), shell=True)

      text_file = open("output.txt",r)  # output.txt is batch file output
```

I expect the code should wait for batch file execution & output of batch file should generate output.txt.
And later text_file = open("output.txt",r) should execute.

But code doesn't wait for batch file execution & sooner generate error that output.txt is not found.

Comment: `START /WAIT` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @MarkSetchell, it works with

```
START /WAIT
```